# Converting query results to actual Product list

Tags: catalogsearch

I get some CatalogSearch results, but I need to convert such results to the corresponding Product list.

How do I convert this:

```
$queryText = Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQueryText();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/query_collection')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQueryFilter($queryText);
```

to a collection of the corresponding products? (I mean: get a corresponding product_collection from this query_collection).